# Interactor - Buffer size for session.recv

Tags: interaction

I am trying to retrieve text data via ssh to a device using `session.connect.ssh`.

The output can contain thousands of lines. When I check the data received in `session.recv`, it seems the number of lines is maxed out at approximately 300. Is there an option to increase the amount of data saved in `session.recv`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
You tagged sed, where does sed come in here?

Comment: How is this relevant to `sed`?